# How can I add a TableItem as a child to a TreeItem in SWT

Tags: java, swt

When I expand a `TreeItem`, I want to show a `Table` with some data populated, instead of the usual tree items. I am not looking for something like `TableTree`.
Below is what I tried

1. Created a Tree(parent)
2. Created a treeItem(TI) within the parent

I want to show a table when I expand TI.

I tried

1. to create a TableItem with parent as TI, but found out it only takes Table as parent.
2. So I tried to create a Table with parent as TI, but found out it takes a Composite as parent, and TreeItem is not a composite

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you having trouble with a particular step or struggling to start at all?

Comment: @Baz The title suggests OP is trying to use TableItem with a Tree.

Comment: @greg-449 From what I understand OP wants to show a whole `Table` within a `TreeItem`. Still that doesn't answer the questions I posted and the question, in the format it is in now, isn't very useful.

Comment: edited the question with details. Thanks